# regular expression to copy an html tag to another place

Tags: regex, tags, copy

In html I need to copy the text that is in the title tag, to a new line as a h1 tag in a certain place..

Example:

```
<TITLE>any text here, including special characters like  .,:- or whataever</TITLE>
```

Output to leave that title as as, and then add a line under this:

under this line:

```
<font face="Arial"><span style="font-size: 14pt">
```

it adds

```
<h1 align="center">any text here, including special characters like  .,:- or whataever</h1>
```

I use notepad++ to search and replace, but I don't think it would work in this case, so please suggest any other simple and effective Windows program to use, wish steps if any..  and I need to edit this in bulk for many files..

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this question is still open, and you have a pretty bad accept rate, I'll try to offer you a solution:

Search for:

```
   <TITLE>(.*)</TITLE>(.*?)<font face="Arial"><span style="font-size: 14pt">
```

And make sure to check the ". matches Newline" option in the search box.  Then use the Following replace:

```
   <TITLE>\1</TITLE>\2<font face="Arial"><span style="font-size: 14pt">\n<h1>\1</h2>
```

Worked in my notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you need yo use should be like:

```
/^<TITLE>(.*)<\/TITLE>/
```

Now I'll give you a small Perl snippet that takes in a line, matches against the above regex and spits out the text in the title tags wrapped in `<h1>`...`</h1>`. Remember that in regexes, the parentheses are used to "group" matches - or in layman terms, to store them for future references. The script:

```
$line = <STDIN>;
chomp $line;
$line =~ /^<TITLE>(.*)<\/TITLE>/;
print "<h1>"."$1"."</h1>";
```

Here, all text between TITLE tags is grouped and hence stored in the variable $1.

When I do:

```
echo "<TITLE>lama</TITLE>" |script.pl
```

I get:

```
<h1>lama</h1>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Yati, I'll give it a go, but I wanna know how to do that? I mean which program I should use to add these lines.  I am totally new to this, and I was just using notepad++

Comment: Take a look at Tim Pietzcker's answer. It is notepad++ specific I see.

Comment: not just notepad++ specific, if it can be done your way, just tell me what I need to do it with, what program or how to run it and I'll try it.. Thanks

Comment: okay, the programming language used in this snippet is Perl: http://www.perl.org/ I suppose you're on Windows, so you'll have to download and install it from the link, place the code above in a file with the extension `pl` (say, script.pl), and then run the `echo` command as shown in cmd.exe, after you `CD` to the folder that contains this file. If all is well, you'll get the o/p as shown. Play around with Perl, and you'll be the master of text processing! You can do complex find-replaces with a few lines of Perl code!

Comment: so I did all the steps but something wrong: downloaded active perl - put the top 4 lines in a file named script.pl - put the script with the .html files in a folder - browsed to that folder in cmd, then entered the line: `echo "<TITLE>(.*)</TITLE>" |script.pl` but nothing changed in the html file! please advise..

Comment: you misunderstood! the script was only to show you how to get the replacement string. Now, you need to find a short tutorial on Perl(there are many). Once you get basic file handling in Perl, you'll figure out on your own how exactly to reflect the changes in the file(s) - though this may take some of your time, but will prove useful if you need to keep doing this stuff over and over again. best of luck :)